# Connecting ireport in netbeans 8.1 with MS SQL Server 2014

Tags: jdbc, jasper-reports, database-connection, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to set a connection between ireport plugin in netbeans with Ms SQL server 2014. i've added a new driver to the netbeans with the latest Microsoft JDBC Drivers 6.0 version. but still have this error:

```
Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=CSG_Project using com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
(The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect.
Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. 
    Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".)
```

Any help?

Comment: Have you checked the config as suggested in the error message? By default SQL Server doesn't listen on port 1433. You need to explicitly configure that.

Comment: i've enabled TCP/IP Protocol and set the TCP Port for the SQL Server Services through SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: The message "Connection refused: connect" means that the port is not open (or the connection was actively blocked by a firewall); there is no further magic involved.

Comment: i'm trying to connect using the jaspersoft designer and the exception is: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver... the jasper plugin cant see the jdbc driver i added in the services tab??